# Datagrid in vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

The inclusion of DataGrid and DatePicker controls was announced for WPF in Framework 4, but when I access to Visual Studio 2010 and I create a WPF project, I don't get these controls. What did I miss? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure the target Framework is set to be v4? They should "just show" in the toolbox if you're targeting v4 of the framework.

Comment: Rowland, the target was set to v3.5 sp1, I changed to V4 and all is OK!! My mistake ... Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your problem, so here we go...
Instead of the DataGrid you can use the ListView with ListView.View set to a GridView. After this you have to create a couple of GridViewColumn objects, set their binding and then add them to the GridView.

I have an example of doing this (but i don't think it is the best one, because i'm kind of new to this programming stuff). If you want I could post it here.

Comment: WPF did not have DataGrid and datepicker controls in previous versions; to solve this situation a free tool called WPF Datagrid toolkit was implemented: http://wpf.codeplex.com/ . But for framework 4 it was announced that WPF would include its own DataGrid / datepicker implementation.

Comment: I was just looking at that web site. Looks promising, but i have no idea if it was included in v4.0.

Comment: There are native controls in the v4 Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613588(v=VS.100).aspx#new_controls